# YII2 PJAX and javascript function call action from controller

Tags: javascript, yii2, pjax

I implement below example for autorefresh of time.(only interval function is set for one sec)

http://blog.neattutorials.com/examples/pjax/web/site/auto-refresh

I use this implementation on my VIEW where i use Inputform and i have trouble that each reload i lost pointer from inputform.

Please is there some way, how Javascript can call function from controller without using button or how i can reload part of page without losing pointer from my text input??

I tried window.location.replace("site/auto-refresh"); but it refresh whole site, and not part of PJAX.

There is my code:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'my-form']); 

echo $form->field($model,'ipadress')->textInput((['id'=>'ipadress'])); $model->text = $text;                      
echo $form->field($model, 'text')->textArea(['rows' => '6','readonly' => 'true']);                    
echo Html::submitButton('Submit',['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>


<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
<?= Html::a("Refresh", ['site/auto-refresh'], ['class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary', 'id' => 'refreshButton',]) ?>
<h1>Current time: <?= $time ?></h1>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>


<?php
$script = <<< JS
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function(){ $("#refressetIntervalhButton").click(); }, 1000);
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

UPDATE:
Still the same result, when time is updated i lost pointer from text input(when i writting).
VIEW:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'my-form']); ?>                     
 <?php echo $form->field($model,'ipadress')->textInput((['id'=>'ipadress'])); 
                        $model->text = $text; ?>                       
<?= $form->field($model, 'text')->textArea(['rows' => '6','readonly' => 'true']) ?>                     
<?= Html::submitButton('Submit',['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
                <?php Pjax::begin(); ?>                
 <?= Html::a("Refresh", ['site/auto-refresh'], ['class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary', 'id' => 'refreshButton',]) ?>
 <h1>Current time: <?= $model->time ?></h1>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Controller:

```
   $model = new \app\models\Tools;
$model->time = date('H:i:s');

            $uptime=shell_exec('uptime | awk \'{print $3}\';');


 return $this->render('auto-refresh', ['uptime' => $uptime, 'text' => $ip,'model' => $model]
```

Thank you 
MK

Comment: use ajax call on set interval function

Comment: Please i am not sure if i understand. Do you mean not use PJAX but AJAX like this:

setInterval(ajaxCall, 1000); 

function ajaxCall() {
and call URL request ???


 
}

I can try it.

Comment: But i try this same but the pointer will not lost.Please keep form action and the time action in controller as same

Answer (score 0):

Please use one controller action for both and add time as public property in your model.

**Controller**

```
public function actionTest()
{   
    $model = new Test();
    $model->time = date('H:i:s');
    return $this->render('TestView', ['model' =>$model]);
}
```

**View**

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
 <?= Html::a("Refresh", ['site/test'], ['class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary', 'id' => 'refreshButton',]) ?>
 <h1>Current time: <?= $model->time ?></h1>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Or you don't want time as public property your controller return like below

```
return $this->render('TestView', ['model' => $model,'time'=>date('H:i:s')]);
```

And use time variable in view directly.

Comment: Please can you check my code UPDATE, when time is updated i lost pointer from text area.  For example i writter IP adress and when is time reloaded i lost MARK or pointer (I am not sure what is right terminology), so i writte only part of ip adress.